# How to fix warning that Keras Layer Input is already depreciated in google colab

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Hi guys i am currently studying machine learning in google colab and right now I experience this error **WARNING:tensorflow:Please add `keras.layers.InputLayer` instead of `keras.Input` to Sequential model. `keras.Input` is intended to be used by Functional model.** in google colab.

Here is my import classes:

```
# Import classes
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout
```

Here is my model Definition:

```
# Model definition
model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(8,)))
model.add(Dense(16,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(8,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
```

Comment: And what is your question? The warning (not error) message literally tells you what to do.

Comment: Also the message does not say anything about deprecation.

Comment: If you don't want to get the warning: replace first layer with: `model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(8,)))`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is recommend to use the functional layer API via `Input`, (which creates an `InputLayer`) without directly using `InputLayer`.

When using `InputLayer` with Keras Sequential model, it can be skipped by moving the input_shape parameter to the first layer after the `InputLayer`. For more details you can refer [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/InputLayer).